# С чего начать изучать Java?

Tags: java

Решил освоить web-программирование, взявшись за обучение Java.
Что посоветуете? Из языков программирования знаю хорошо Delphi и немного php.
Что следует почитать для начала и какую лучше IDE использовать?
Хочу освоить Java за короткие сроки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Двухтомник Хорстманна (ну это так для начала), как с ним разберешься, переходи на 1 из этих книг:

[Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3 Application Server](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1849510369/ref=cm_sw_su_dp)

[Beginning Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3](http://www.amazon.com/dp/143022889X/ref=cm_sw_su_dp)

ммм... про ide eclipse или netbeanse (мне eclipse больше нравится)

Comment: Ах да забыл написать, буду писать на java скорее всего на Windows. Так что насчет кроссплатформенности по выбору IDE на замарачивайтесь.

Comment: 2 тома для быстрого изучения? Тем более я почитал немного, там поясняется практически всё, даже что точку с запятой надо ставить и зачем. Я имел ввиду именно книгу или материал, для тех кто уже знает азы программирования. С таким материалом я точно буду долго изучать Java.

Comment: .... без основ Java SE вы далеко не уедите...

Comment: В чем вообще разница между этими платформами JAVA EE, JAVA SE и т.д. ?

Comment: посмотреть в википедии не судьба? 
Java EE -  Java Enterprise Edition (если знаете, что такое ASP.NET, то поймете) предназначено для веб
Java ME -  Java Micro Edition (то, что вам нужно) предназначено для мобильных устройств
Java SE - Java Standard Edition (основа основ) стандартное издание Javа, не зная этого лезть в ME или в EE не имеет смысла, если вы конечно хотите основательно разобраться в платформе.
еще есть JavaFX если ничего не путаю, то предназначено для создания графический интерфейсов.

Comment: Вот уж java для мобильных устройств мне точно не нужно. Мне нужны для среднего объема ПО. Естественно для десктопа.

Comment: извините))) перепутал ))

Answer (score 4):

Из книг рекомендую: Брюс Эккель — Философия Java (4-е издание) и Джошуа Блох — Java. Эффективное программирование. Все начинающие джависты должны их прочитать.

У каждого свои предпочтения к IDE: начни с NetBeans, т.к. она попроще. Если интересно, то ставь Eclipse и IntelliJ IDEA и выбирай, что тебе лучше по нраву.

Удачи!

Comment: Это и правда полезный материал, спасибо. Насчет IDE, IntelliJ IDEA - как то немного непонятно, Eclipse - больше понравилась,NetBeans - что то слишком прожорлива к системе.

Answer (score 0):

[[@Пандакун](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD)](/users/3324/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD), Вы закрыли вопрос,  поэтому в коментариях, т.к. Вы ниже писали про объем рекомендуемых книг.

К. Арлольд, Д.Гослинг: Язык программирования JAVA

Плюс книги в том, что она *маленькая* (в отличие от других).

--

Откровенно скажу, ее прочел первой (давно, лет 15 назад), но мне не понравилось (вообще язык (точнее набор классов java) по прочтении этой книги не понравился), но недавно пришлось его осваивать (писать программы) и я прочел сначала Эккеля и потом Хорстмана.

Вот тут я "въехал" и изменил свой взгляд на Java.